# What's the best way to structure these relationships? To HABTM or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, has-and-belongs-to-many

Just looking for some advice on how to structure my relationships in an app that I'm making.  I have the following models:

```
activity # golf, karaoke
event    # golf competition followed by all-night karaoke boat party
post     # write-up of the golf and karaoke event mentioned above
gallery  # photos from the golf and karaoke event
```

**Question 1**

- each **event** can involve *more than one activity*
- each **activity** can be associated with *more than one event*

Do I need a **habtm** between activity and event?

---

**Question 2**

- each **event** can be reported in *more than one blog post*
- a **post** can report on *more than one event*

Should I use a **habtm** between event and post?

---

**Question 3**

- each **post** can include images from *more than one gallery*
- a **gallery** can be included in *more than one post*

Is this another **habtm**?

---

**Question 4** - It's conceivable that the admins might want to link 1 or more sets of photos with 1 or more events, without creating a blog post to tie everything together.  Would it be advisable to declare a **habtm** relationship between galleries and events?

---

**For bonus points:**  Is an app with this many habtm's likely to be slower than one which enforces one-to-many relationships between the same models?  Is there a suggested limit to the number of habtm relationships an app an have before it becomes too complex?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cases needs habtm. It follows from your specyfication. You can only wonder if you really need such relations. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it "YAGNI".
I would not also think about speed during developement. When your app will be slow, add caching.